# Is creating flux from a list an optimized solution for reactive programming?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a blocking data store, that returns the List.
In order to be reactive, should I convert this list to a flux(or Mono, depending on the return value) and then process?

List has another List. Can I use Stream to process the interim value or convert this to a Flux using  Flux.fromIterable?

I am trying to understand the best practices and where reactive programming would yield best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is the difference between a `Mono` and a `Flux`?

The difference is that a `Flux` is a `List<Mono>` (for simplicity). And what is a `Mono`? it is something of the type T. So what does this mean in your case.

Well if you fetch a `List<T>` you can either put this in a `Mono<List<T>` or you can put this in a `Flux<T>`.

If you put this list using `Flux#fromIterable` each item in the list will sort of become a `Mono` and the `Flux` will emit that item when available.

Since you have a blocking call that returns an entire `List<T>` If you put this in a `Mono` the subscriber will get the entire list in one big emit. If it is a really big list it can put strain on the `subscriber` because the publisher might emit one giant list of say 1 000 000 items in one big chunk.

If a big list is put in a `Flux` the `subscriber` can limit and ask the service to emit items in a more controlled manor, for example in 10 batches of 100 000 items each.

So i personally would recommend to put the list in a `Flux`.

But none of this has any significant performance gain on your application. It's more a feature that calling `subscribers` can gain.

To prevent major slowdowns in your application it is important that your blocking calls are made using its own thread. This can be achived using the `Schedulers.elastic()` that will spawn a new thread for long going tasks. And then kill that thread after default 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your answer. Could you please help me understand if using functional programming to process the jdbc response and then wrapping the response as a MONO or FLUX is a right thing to do or rather using I should transform the JDBC response to a FLUX <T>containing FLUX <T1> and process it further.

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: I wanted to understand if instead of processing the list(returned from the datastore) as is using Streams, should I create a Flux and then process the information or should I rather use Stream and then wrap the response as Flux?